# 14.04: kernel version vs. release version

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, do-release-upgrade

I started fresh installation from the ISO file of 14.04.1 via USB flash drive. Soon after that, I did the updating via Software Updater (over 270 MB required). Then I've checked the terminal and this is what is happening now:

```
:~$ uname -r

3.13.0-93-generic

:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Release:    14.04

Codename:   trusty
```

As far as I'm concerned, the point release 14.04.5 is along with 4.4 kernel. How could it happen to be as what is shown in the command line? Would there be any problems that might appear caused by it? Should I upgrade the kernel?

Comment: If you were doing a fresh install, why didn't you just get the ISO for 14.04.5 at http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/? It seems convoluted to me that you installed 14.04.1 and then upgraded it. In any case, what commands did you type to do the upgrade? Generally, you would need to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: The only Ubuntu ISO I have at home is 14.04.1. The reason I want to upgrade to a newer release is because I realise that 14.04.1 is old even though it's been said that it's supported till 2019. So, should I upgrade the kernel? Or if I decided to stay with kernel 3.13, would there be any problems? Can kernel 3.13 handle the 14.04.5? I am worried about overheating.

Comment: I generally recommend upgrading the kernel. That said, it is difficult to tell with utter certainty if the new kernel will break your system unless you try it or if people with your hardware/software have tried it and complained about it, but I am betting it will not.